# Showing error when create a new Project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want create a new Android project in Android Studio, but finished the create project show me this errors

My Android Studio version : 1.3.2

[image: error image]

please help me to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the **support libraries v23**,you **have to compile your project with API23**.

In your `build.gradle` change the `compileSdkVersion` to **23**.

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
```

If you don't want to use api 23 to compile (pay attention, compileSdk and targetSdk are different), you have to use the support libraries v22 (compiling with api22).

Change in your `build.gradle` the dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

Something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        //...
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    //...

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

Comment: tnx, i cant downlaod sdk v23 :( , how to use v22 ?

Comment: @ctfvgh why? You can compile with api 23 and target 22. Otherwise, you have to use the appcompat v22. Check the updated answer.

Comment: @ctfvgh As described in answer if you can't use api 23, you can still use api 22 but using the support libraries v22.

Comment: tnx, Can you send me the code for the v22? my mean is Gradl.build codes for v22, tnx

Comment: you are great maaaaaaaaaan, tnx <3